# adcfgclone.pl dbconfig fails when trying to configure the database to use logical host names

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, setup

adcfgclone.pl dbconfig fails when trying to configure the database to use logical host names. Unable to make database connection, error in ApplyDatabase.log
"   Exception occurred: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    Connection could not be obtained; returning null"

Database version: 12.1.0.2
Oracle E-Business Suit version : 12.1.3

Steps performed:
1. Adpreclone.pl run on apps tier and two database node (2 node rac database)
2. Created context file on the first database node to use logical hostname.
3. adcfgclone.pl dbconfig being run to configure the database to use logical name. Error at this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vip name from /etc/hosts was being used for the setup and causing the error.
Corrected the context file to use the name specifies with physical name and the issue was resolved.